Except for $1$, are there any perfect powers in the sequence $1,122,122333,\cdots,122333\cdots\underbrace{nnn\cdots n}_{n \text{ times}}$?
Other than $1$, is there any perfect powers in the sequence $1,122,122333,\cdots,122333\cdots\underbrace{nnn\cdots n}_{n \text{ times}}$?
This is sequence A098129.
We certainly know that this is not a perfect if $n=2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ and by brute force, we can see that this is not a perfect power.
But what about when $n\geq10$?
I know these facts:

If we want $122333\cdots\underbrace{nnn\cdots n}_{n \text{ times}}$ to be a square number, then $n$ must be $\geq400$ if $n$ is divisible by $4$, as when we divide
$122333\cdots\underbrace{nnn\cdots n}_{n \text{ times}}$ by $4$, we will always obtain a number that is equal to $5\pmod{8}$ unless $n$ is an even perfect square between $100$ to $399$.


If we desire $122333\cdots\underbrace{nnn\cdots n}_{n \text{ times}}$ to be a perfect 5th power, then the last two digits must be either $1,7,24,32,43,49,51,57,68,75,76,93,$ or $99$.

If $n$ is even, and the highest power of $2$ that divides $122333\cdots\underbrace{nnn\cdots n}_{n \text{ times}}$ is odd, then $122333\cdots\underbrace{nnn\cdots n}_{n \text{ times}}$ must be a (highest odd power of $2$ that divides $122333\cdots\underbrace{nnn\cdots n}_{n \text{ times}}$)th power. For example, if $n=224$, then $122333\cdots\underbrace{224\cdots 224}_{224 \text{ times}}$ must be a perfect 5th power as the highest odd power of $2$ that divides $224$ is $32$.


Via Pari GP, I tried to check that all values of $n\leq10^{4}$ to check if $122333\cdots\underbrace{nnn\cdots n}_{n \text{ times}}$ is ever a perfect power other than $n=1$, but so far, it was unsuccessful.
Note: $122333\cdots\underbrace{nnn\cdots n}_{n \text{ times}}$ is a number like, for example, if $n=2024$, then it is equal to $122333\cdots\underbrace{2024\cdots 2024}_{2024 \text{ times}}$.

$10^4$ is a substantial search limit in this case. If no perfect power appeared upto that point , it is extraordinary unlikely that there is one.

An interesting question is also whether such a number can be prime. I found none with $100\ 000$ digits or less.
